# How do I open android built in downloads app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher

So I'm downloading stuff and it gets put into the built in downloads app since thats how the download manager works. I just want to the user to click a button which opens the built in downloads app.
Heres my try:

```
btnDownloads.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PackageManager pakMan=MainActivity.context.getPackageManager();
        Log.d("bebr", "Making pak");
        if(pakMan!=null){
            Intent downloadsIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.downloads","com.android.downlods.Downloads"));
            ResolveInfo resolved=pakMan.resolveActivity(downloadsIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            Log.d("bebr","Resolving");
            if(resolved!=null){
                Log.d("bebr", "Starting");
                startActivity(downloadsIntent);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Ok finally managed to get the solution:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: Yea the package name is a total guess.

Comment: Heres the package name but it gives an error that he activity isnt defined in te manifest(Even when it is)
<code>07-05 09:19:01.398: I/ActivityManager(135): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.providers.downloads.ui/.DownloadList} from pid 354</code>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS) constant:

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know the package name to launch the Downloads application. I am not certain that it is the same on every device either (though it may be). You can find it by watching the Logcat and launching it you should see some line in the log that has the package name in it.

However you can skip the downloads app completely and launch the package installer directly (which is what will happen when the user selects your apk in the downloads app)

just fill in the path to the file in the following snippet:

```
File appFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.apk");
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("file:/"+ appFile.getAbsolutePath());
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(appFile),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily using the download manager to download an app. Your suggestion helped though and now i know the pakage for the downloads app(It gives an error though that the activity os not defined in the manifest so it doesnt open):
    $07-05 09:19:01.398: I/ActivityManager(135): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.providers.downloads.ui/.DownloadList} from pid 354